# Using HttpClient in WCF Service

Tags: .net, wcf, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a static instance of  `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` within a Service Method (`OperationContract`) of WCF Service.

Since WCF Request as Per-Call, that means I will have a new HttpClient instance created for every WCF Request. Will this result in a out of port exceptions or the instance of HttpClient shall be disposed once the WCF Per Call Request is completed.

--Update--

I created a Single class with Static HttpClient and initialized the HttpClient properties during Global Initialization in WCF.

Comment: Put it in a static field! No need to instantiate it per call.

Answer (score 0):

It will be disposed every time the request is completed.The PerCall instance strategy means that WCF generates a new service instance for each client request, and the instances will not affect each other. After the client call ends, the server immediately destroys the instance.

You can also dispose it yourself after using Httpclient:

```
  using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()) {...
}
```